# You have an error in your SQL syntax (...) near ;

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I got this message, and I couldn't find any error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where id ='null'' at line 1

I assumed this code was wrong, but it turned out it isn't.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select password" +
                                 "from userinfo where id = '" + id + "';");
```

This is full code of error file.

```
 private boolean checkLoginInfo(String id, String password) throws ServletException
 {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdb", "root", "1234");
            if (conn == null)
                throw new Exception("can't connect to database.<BR>");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select password" +
                                            " from userinfo where id = '" + id + "';"); 
                if (!rs.next()) 
                   return false;
                String correctPassword = rs.getString("password");
                if (password.equals(correctPassword))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        }
```

Comment: did you check whether the id is not null before invokings checkloginInfo method.

Comment: Is `null` a valid password? You should probably validate your inputs before sending them to the database (re: SQL injection attacks)

Comment: Do you have a space before "from" or not? There is one in the full code but not in the extract.

Comment: Also, you seem to be storing passwords in plaintext in the database. That's a really, really bad idea.

Comment: @VickyS Yes, I did. Thank you for comment.

Comment: @Mureinik No it is not a valid password. Thank you for comment

Comment: @JJJ Yes, I have a space before `from`. Thank you for recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **missing space** between *password* and *from*:

```
select password" + "from userinfo where id = '" + id + "';"
```

**Try this**:

```
"SELECT password FROM `userinfo` WHERE id = '"+id+"'"
```

You should **furthermore** read about:

1. Escaping SQL queries
2. Authentication/Authorization (why do you select the password only?)
3. Code formatting

**Edit 1:**
The error messages tells us, you are setting the `id` to `'null'` (String, because of ''), not `NULL`. If your `id` is expecting an Integer, but you are providing a String, it will break.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I changed my query, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @lee1707 what type (e.g. Integer) is the field `id`? Is it allowed to be `NULL`? What's the latest error message? You are setting the value to `'null'`, which is a string. If your field expects an Integer or `NULL`, this could be the mistake.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. I forgot to recompile the java. You were right and Thank you a lot.(Id type is string and not allowed to be null)

Comment: @lee1707 Happy to help. Please mark my answer as the right one, if it helped you. Thanks. :-)